# Is it possible to pause nagios notification escalation?

Tags: nagios

If i set up a nagios alert notification escalation definition, is it possible to somehow tell nagios to pause escalation while someone who's notified earlier tries to fix the problem?

e.g. if the web server starts flapping but someone tries to fix it, there's no need to notify people further up the chain.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use *Acknowledge this service problem* command on the service's page.

> This command is used to acknowledge a
>   service problem. When a service
>   problem is acknowledged, future
>   notifications about problems are
>   temporarily disabled until the service
>   changes from its current state. If you
>   want acknowledgement to disable
>   notifications until the service
>   recovers, check the 'Sticky
>   Acknowledgement' checkbox. Contacts
>   for this service will receive a
>   notification about the
>   acknowledgement, so they are aware
>   that someone is working on the
>   problem. Additionally, a comment will
>   also be added to the service. Make
>   sure to enter your name and fill in a
>   brief description of what you are
>   doing in the comment field. If you
>   would like the service comment to
>   remain once the acknowledgement is
>   removed, check the 'Persistent
>   Comment' checkbox. If you do not want
>   an acknowledgement notification sent
>   out to the appropriate contacts,
>   uncheck the 'Send Notification'
>   checkbox.

For more information, see http://www.bulletproof.net.au/Tutorials/How-to-acknowledge-an-alert.aspx